# What payment processors will be supported in core for 4.7?

Tags: payment-processor, recurring-contributions

For a new client install, we need to pick a supported payment processor. Many questions about payment processors support appear in this forum, in the civicrm forums and elsewhere.  The [Wiki](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC43/Payment+Processors#PaymentProcessors-ProcessorComparisonChart) lists many and there are several [extensions](https://civicrm.org/extensions/home?title=payment&body_value=&field_extension_cms_tid=All&sort_by=field_extension_current_usage_value&sort_order=DESC), with various levels of support and capabilities.

There is a general extension to support [omnipay](https://civicrm.org/extensions/omnipay-multiprocessor-extension) but that does not support the latest (4.6.5) version and has not had much traction.  Also, [4.7](https://civicrm.org/blogs/totten/timeline-47) will substantially refactor payment processing.

I would normally turn to paypal as that is in core and likely dominant, but the wiki notes say it is migrating to payflow and recurring payments require an additional fee, so I'm skeptical that this may pose risk in future versions.

Would appreciate suggestions on how to select a payment processor that will be well supported.

Answer (score 5):

Omnipay should work with the latest version - but is only relevant if a processor you wish to use is currently offered through it.

If you want recurring in the US you should probably consider
IATS
Paypal
Authorize.net

in that order.

IATS is most actively developed & IATS has been investing in Civi development itself & the other 2 have the most traction - although Authorize.net has some real technical gaps - ie. they don't retry IPNS.

If you do go with IATS you should use their customer referral programme as your customer will save $100 that way. IATS will also either give you $100 or donate it to CiviCRM if you (like us) prefer not that in order to maintain neutrality http://home.iatspayments.com/civicrm-referral

Comment: That's very helpful Eileen. Looking at IATS I see they support clients in Canada and UK as well as US. Big advantages over Paypal that I can see are a) ACH / Direct Debits, in addition to credit cards, and b) no mandatory emails to customers every time a recurring payment is taken.

Comment: Wow - Omnipay seems "too good to be true" with support for so many processors and lot's of github activity.  What's the catch?  Could Civicrm get out of the processor support business?  Anything else relevant planned for 4.7 payment/order API that could have big impact on processor support?

Comment: The catch I think is that there is always going to be a bit more complexity than it can handle for some processors. Omnipay is all about standardisation - but they fiercly resist that :-)

I think we will need to maintain the ability to write processor specific extensions even if many of them do move to Omnipay for flexibility